# Is It Possible to Attach multiple Ports to a TC Filter?

Tags: linux, bandwidth, qos, tc

I need to limit the bandwidth/rate by ports, and as a server there would be thousands of ports. Due to the limit of tc filter, I wonder if it is possible for multiple discreate ports to share a same filter.

For example, suppose we have 10 ports, they are 11000, 12000, ... and 20000, can we populates these ports into a same tc filter?